# why is my following code not printing the value stored in char variable

Tags: pointers, char

i've tried to run the following program but there is this warning showing up
warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]|

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[1];
    if(1)
    {
        name[0]="syed";
    }
    printf("%s",name);
}
```

Comment: you're confusing char and string.  A `char` is a single character. `"` gives you a string (which decays to a `char *`).  A `char[1]` can only hold an empty string (length 0)

Comment: char name[1] is an array size of one it can hold one string word right so name [0] = "syed" now at index position 0 syed is stored right ?

Comment: No - it can hold one `char`, which for a string can only be the NUL terminator (for a 0-length string max).  `"syed"` is not a char (its a string of size 5/length 4), so this assignment is an error (and strings can't be assigned with `=` anyways).